# How can I tell the year my bike was made

Tags: mountain-bike

[image]  how can I tell what my bike is worth[image]

Comment: I cannot see the model ?

Comment: Blurry photo taken at what seems to be a street encampment. Are you sure this bike wasn’t stolen?

Comment: @Max It's a Specialized Enduro... probably around year 2006 - 2008

Comment: @KolobCanyon Please don’t post answers as comments. Comments circumvent our quality control mechanisms and they aren’t searchable.

Comment: Its worth whatever it sells for.   We don't do valuations because they're localised, of short term usage, impossible to vett or verify, and not a good fit for the long-term useful archive that SE is growing.  Steel is 1-10cents per kilo as scrap, if you want to go weigh it.  Aluminium is more at 10c-$10 USD per kilo depending on quality and alloy.

Answer (score 2):

You could google the model name and see when it was introduced.

You can check the components models (brakes, shifters, derailleurs...) to see when they were introduced.

That should give you a starting point.

You also could try contacting Specialized.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is difficult to read the type on your slightly fuzzy picture, several details suggest that it's an enduro or downhill type Specialized: massive frame, fairly long front travel, big brake discs, rear triangle that allows big swings.

Searching for Specialized and enduro produced a nice survey suggesting that it dates from 2005-2006.
https://www.pinkbike.com/news/the-evolution-of-the-specialized-enduro-2016.html

[image]

Comment: That's it. Based on my similar year Enduro, it's probably worth about $500

Comment: @KolobCanyon please don't give valuations - they're off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways:

Google the brand and model and guesses at the year, select 'images'. Trawl through the images until you find one that matches your bike.

Go the [Bicycle Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/), look up brand/model, guess year, trawl through images and specs until you find one that matches. That will also get you an idea of what you can sell the bike for.